# Chaining multiple Jquery events with OR operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm creating a panel that slides down when the user focuses the search box.
I'm terrible at Jquery but still learning, I've managed to create the basic functionality:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".search-panel").hide();
  $("#search_form [type='text']")
    .focus(function() {
      $(".search-panel").slideDown("fast");
    })
    .focusout(function() {
      $(".search-panel").slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

with this basic functionality clicking outside the text box will fold up the panel I'm trying to implement a complex set of conditions whereby:

```
IF (textbox.focus) { show search panel}

IF (texbox.losefocus) && ( NOT search-panel.mouseover)
&& ( NOT (anything-in-search-panel-is-focused) )
```

basically I need to make sure that the user is not hovering over or interacting with the panel in some way and that the textbox is not focused before I slide it up.

JsFiddle of current situation:
http://jsfiddle.net/b9g9d6gf/

Comment: Can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or the HTML?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b9g9d6gf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `.focusout()` function, you should bind a click function on the document.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".search-panel").hide();
    $("#search_form [type='text']")
        .focus(function () {
        $(".search-panel").slideDown("fast");
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if( !( $(e.target).is('#search_form *')) ){
           $(".search-panel").slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

If the document is clicked, anywhere, it looks if the target isn't a element inside `#search_form`. If not, it will slide up the `.search-panel`.

Note:
I removed the label and changed the span to labels. Clicking a label will also (un)check the checkbox inside it. Having three checkboxes making it act wrong. So either make three separate labels (instead of span) or remove it.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b9g9d6gf/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b9g9d6gf/5/)**

```
<script>

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
 {
var container = $("#search_form");

if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{
    $(".search-panel").slideUp("fast");
}
else
   {
    $(".search-panel").slideDown("fast");
    $("#search_form [type='text']").focus();
   }
});

</script>
```

Comment: This one actually slides up and down quickly if a checkbox is checked, not ideal, but thanks for the help

Comment: oh it was wrong update Link what i have gave to you , have a look on edited answer post link @davegri